# When debugging using Visual Studio 2010 C#, how to avoid stepping into common functions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

There is a guide in google, but it is poorly described.
http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/visual-studio-msvc-debugging-NoStepInto.html

Comment: I don't think I understand your question - why not use F10 to step over?

Comment: I have a common function to write logs. It's just annoying having to step through this function when debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could the [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) be what you are looking for?

```
using System.Diagnostics;
class Foo
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    int Bar()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```